# Why isn't `:set tw=n` wrapping text in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm new to Vim and trying to set my text width for automatic wrapping. Having worked through the tutorial and read the help documentation, I don't understand why the command `:set tw=78` isn't doing the trick. My `.vimrc` file contains the statement:
`autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78`
, which also has not resulted in wrapped text. Thanks for your patience with a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You have to format the text after assigning a value to `textwidth`, use `gggqG`: `gg` to set cursor at the beginning of the file, `gq` to start formatting and `G` to format until end of file. It is a `normal` instruction, so I added it before the command.

```
autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78 | normal gggqG
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `'textwidth'` isn't enough. You also need to add `t` to `'formatoptions'` (see `:help 'formatoptions'`). From `:help 'fo-table'`:

```
letter       meaning when present in 'formatoptions'

t            Auto-wrap text using textwidth
...
```

So you may want to use this autocommand:

```
autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78 formatoptions+=t
```